# set `CC='clang'` with `export`, but `./configure` is still using `gcc`

Tags: r, gcc, makefile, configure

Compiling `R` from the R-devel `svn` branch, I do

```
export CC='clang'
export CXX='clang++'
sudo ./configure
```

but the configuration script still tries to use `gcc` as the compiler. Why?

Comment: Sorry for the self post, but this was a really dumbo mistake which I hope someone else googles to save themselves the embarrassingly large amount of time I just wasted.

Comment: This is not good practice. Build the package as user first, and then `sudo make install` if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Because `sudo` reads environment variables of the **root** user, but `export` saves shell variables to *your* user environment. (within that terminal session only)

### To fix this, you need to configure with `sudo -E ./configure`,

which reads environment variables from your user account (= login name) when executing `./configure` with heightened privileges.  Also have a look at the `sudo -H` flag (within `man sudo`).

---

Or you can first `sudo su` into the root account and `export CC='clang'` from within that root shell.

(the root shell prompt might begin with a `#` rather than a `$`, and be missing other config niceties—eg colourisation—from `/home/user/.bashrc`)